# Magento 2 : Double qty before add to cart

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, addtocart

how to change the functionality of add to cart button like I click on add to cart then qty should be doubled?

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $isSaleable = $_product->isSaleable();?>
<?php //if($_product->getFinalPrice() > 0){ ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 2 ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" <?php echo ($_product->isVirtual() && $isSaleable)?'':'disabled'; ;?>>
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php if($isSaleable):?>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it ! Don't forget to upvote/mark as answered :)

On your custom module:
**/etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="restrict_sales_model_cart_add_before" instance="vendor\module\Observer\CartAddingConditionCheck" />
    </event>
```

**/Observer/CartAddingConditionCheck.php**

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class CartAddingConditionCheck implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $product;

    public function __construct(
       RedirectInterface $redirect,
       Product $product,
    )
    {
        $this->request         = $request;
        $this->product         = $product;
    }
    
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    )
    {   
        $postValues = $this->request->getPostValue();
        $item = $this->product;   
        if ($item->getParentItem()) 
        {
            $item = $item->getParentItem();
        }
        $quantity         = isset($postValues['qty']) ? $postValues['qty'] : 1;
        

        $item->setQty($quantity * 2);
     }
}
?>
```